# Incompatible java.lang.Integer value assigned to parameter SUBREPORT_DIR

Tags: jasper-reports

Let me depict a situation: I have a report A and subreports B and C. A uses B and B uses C. Default value of `SUBREPORT_DIR` in A is `$P{CUSTOM_SUBREPORT_DIR}`. In A.jrxml I see:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{CUSTOM_SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="CUSTOM_SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

I also need a proper value of `SUBREPORT_DIR` in B so I passed it using iReport (Subreport properties/Parameters) so in `A.jrxml` I have:

```
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```

And when I'm trying to generate report A I get `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Incompatible java.lang.Integer value assigned to parameter SUBREPORT_DIR in the B dataset.`

I'm sure that `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` isn't an integer and type of `SUBREPORT_DIR` parameter in B subreport is String. All reports I made using iReport 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (I do it in this way and it works):

Define the parameters in report A:

```
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_B_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" />
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_C_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" />
```

Define subreport B in report A. Here I use DataSource for report B from parameter. Also I send a parameter to subreport B with the subreport C directory and another parameter with DataSource for report C.

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="583" height="10" />
    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_C_DIR">
         <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_C_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <subreportParameter name="SubReportCDataSource">
         <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SubReportCDataSource}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{SubReportBDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_B_DIR} + "B.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Finally, in subreport B, define subreport C:

```
<subreport>
        <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="583" height="10" />
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{SubReportCDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_C_DIR} + "C.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```